# Dis-engage a globally enabled module using the axis2-admin

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I tried to dis-engage a module (modulue-x) in Axis2 using the axis2-admin.

[image]

But it gives me the error saying.

> Can not disengage modulue-x . This module is engaged at a higher
>   level.

So, then I noted that modulue-x has been enabled globally for all services. I checked for an option to disable the modulue-x globally. But couldn't find how to do this using the axis2-admin.

Does anyone have a tip on this?